# Can two players play Mortal Kombat 11 using single pair of joycon?

Tags: controllers, nintendo-switch, mortal-kombat-11

A lot of games for Nintendo Switch are supporting hotseat for two players using a single joycon each.

Now that *Mortal Kombat 11* is released on Nintendo Switch, I wonder if game supports hotseat in this manner, or if it actually needs two gamepads with full keys layout.

Comment: Minor nitpick: "[**Hotseat**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotseat_%28multiplayer_mode%29)" refers to a multiplayer mode, where players trade seats to play. It's used in turn-based games, where players don't need to play at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Glad to say they can.
There’s a horizontal preset for each controller so that serves as a (customizable) alternative to the normal preset (also customizable).
When I say customizable I mean you can choose between normal and two other presets with varying keys mapped elsewhere. And you also get the ability to edit the presets.

Comment: Just checked, you are right. I was a little bit confused by how "separate players mode" is enabled on Switch, but managed it to work.